# Why isn't panel head showing in bootstrap when I use a form?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to have a from that contains a panel heading but the panel heading doesn't show when I include the form. As soon as I include a form within the markup the panel heading background disappears. How do I resolve this?

With form:

```
<div class="col-md-11 pane top30">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<form action="">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

[image]

Without form:

```
<div class="col-md-11 pane top30">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just put the `<form>` inside `panel-body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your form outside the `panel`

```
<form action="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     ....
    </div>
</form>
```

*Why it was not working* : bootstrap defines the heading css like this

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading
 {
 }
```

So in this case `panel-heading` css affects only when it is direct child of `.panel-default`
but in your case `panel-heading` is direct child of `form`.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTNym/)

Comment: I think I'm having one of those days.. Will mark answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

`Why isn't panel head showing in bootstrap when I use a form?`

CSS is often based on things like `nth-child` - so the heading should be the first child of the panel in order for it to work correctly.